# Convert model to List<Object> of fields

Tags: java, list, object, reflection

I would like to find an efficient way of converting any object to the `List<Object>` of it's fields so for example:

```
public class User {
   private String name; // John
   private String surname; // Wick
   private int age; // 55
}
```

would end up as List with the next elements: `{"John", "Wick", 55}.`

I know I can do it using reflection but are there any ObjectUtils or ReflectionUtils methods that are already doing that?

Answer (score 0):

I did a method that should help you. Your class must contain a "getter" for each attribute. Ex:

```
name -> getName();
```

[Online example](https://repl.it/@ErwanSturzenegg/ReflexionUtilsSampleForStackOverFlow)

### User.java

```
import java.lang.String;

public class User {
   private String name;
   private String surname;
   private int age; 

  public User(){
    this.name = "John";
    this.surname = "Wick";
    this.age =55;
  }

   public String getName(){
     return this.name;
   }
   public String getSurname(){
     return this.surname;
   }
   public int getAge(){
     return this.age;
   }
}
```

### Main.java

```
import java.util.List;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    User u = new User();

    List<Object> list = ReflexionUtils.getListOfFields(u);
    for(Object o : list){
      System.out.println(o);
    }
  }
}
```

### ReflexionUtils.java

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.List;
import java.lang.String;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;    
import java.lang.reflect.Method; 

public class ReflexionUtils {

  public static List<Object>  getListOfFields(Object bean){
    List<Object> result = new ArrayList<Object>();
    for (Field f : bean.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
      try{
        String name = f.getName();
          name = name.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + name.substring(1);
        Method m = bean.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("get"+name, null);
        Object o = m.invoke(bean, null);
        result.add(o);
      } catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
      }
    }
    return result;
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

For simplicity, override toString() method of User class and then convert it to `List<Object>`.

```
public class User {
    private String name; // John
    private String surname; // Wick
    private int age; // 55

    public User(String name, String surname, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return ""+getName()+ ", "+getSurname()+", "+getAge()+"";
    }
}
```

Then convert:

```
User a  = new User("John","Wick",55);
List<Object> items = Arrays.asList(a.toString().split("\\s*,\\s*"));
```

It gives output like this:

```
[John, Wick, 55]
```